# Unable to remove left/right padding from Vuetify's Toolbar component (Spacing helpers not working)

Tags: css, vue.js, vuetify.js

v-toolbar component has `default left` and `right padding 24px` each(desktop version). It can't be overridden.

I've tried Vuetify's spacing helpers (pa-0,ma-0) but all they do is push the logo under the padding(You can see in the picture). I've also tried css classes(padding-left: 0,padding: 0). But padding stays there. Using DevTools I found out that the class that it uses is "v-toolbar__content" so in `<style></style>` section I've tried `padding:0 and padding-left:0` but nothing changed.

```
<v-toolbar>
 <v-toolbar-title class="pa-0">
  <span>
   <v-avatar size="40px" tile>
    <img src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2016/08/25/07/30/red-1618916_960_720.png" />
    <h1>Title</h1>
    </v-avatar>
   </span>
 </v-toolbar-title>
</v-toolbar>
```

So when i add class="pa-0" or class="pl-0" or overriding the padding of the "v-toolbar__content" class, I'm expecting the padding to disappear but it doesn't.
[Here is an example in sandbox.io editor.](https://codesandbox.io/s/vuetify-dialog-example-yk7cb)
[image: Here is a Picture with example of the problem.]

Comment: Without a [mcve] there's little to no chance of getting any help with CSS issues. Or are you expecting anyone to create a new vue app with Vuetify and test your code? If you are, the chances are quite slim. Note pictures help when you actually provide some running code (to emphasize on what the problem is). But without running code, they're pretty much useless. On creating a minimal example, if you need multi-file environment, you could use codesandbox.io

Comment: @AndreiGheorghiu you are absolutely right, i will provide a code example shortly. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Solved it like this.
Overwriting  v-toolbar__content css class wasn't working because i had the 'scoped' keyword in the style tag. Once i removed it, it worked and removed the padding.

```
<style>
    .v-toolbar__content {
      padding-left: 0px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks! I had same issue as Vuetify 2 v-app-bar with prominent (`.v-toolbar--prominent`) adds 4px top padding. I was struggling to get v-toolbar-items flush with the toolbar - removed `scoped` and added `!important` worked for me: `.v-toolbar__content {padding-top: 0 !important; }`